# Cygwin: Going from a 32 Bit File to 64 Bit

Tags: linux, unix, cygwin, nasm, elf

I am following a tutorial online made a while back and it says to use

`ld -s -o testing test.o`

to create an output file.

I'm getting the error of

`ld: i386 architecture of input file 'test.o' is incompatible with i386:x86-64 output`

when trying to run that line.

`Test.o` was created by `nasm -f elf test.asm`. It can't be created in 64-bit format sadly.

How should I go about combating this? Thanks so much for your time!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a 64bit executable with 32bit code.

If you want to make a 32bit executable, you can use `-m elf_i386`:

```
$ ld -s -o test test.o
ld: i386 architecture of input file `test.o' is incompatible
    with i386:x86-64 output
$ ld -s -o test test.o -m elf_i386
$
```

Comment: I received an `ld: unrecognised emulation mode: ` error while doing this, any ideas why? I'm completely new to linux so any and all help is much appreciated

Comment: @BeccaBohem Use `ld -V` to list the emulation modes supported by your linker.

Comment: how did you build the test.o ?

Comment: I compiled it with `gcc -m32`